how to prevent user to escape full screen in next js
I am using version 14 of Next.js, and I want to write code for a scenario where when a user clicks the start button, it goes into full screen. Now, when the user presses Escape for the first time, they should receive a warning saying 'Are you sure you want to exit full view?' If the user presses Escape again, then the screen should exit. I wrote some code with the help of ChatGPT, but it's not working at all. Can anyone help me rewrite this code?
 "use client";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
    export default function Test() {
      const [isFullScreen, setIsFullScreen] = useState(false);
      const [warningShown, setWarningShown] = useState(false);
    
      const goFullScreen = () => {
        const elem = document.documentElement;
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          /* Firefox */
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
          /* IE/Edge */
          elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
        setIsFullScreen(true);
        setWarningShown(false);
      };
    
      const exitFullScreen = () => {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          /* Firefox */
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
          /* IE/Edge */
          document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
        setIsFullScreen(false);
      };
    
      console.log(isFullScreen)
      useEffect(() => {
        const handleEsc = (event) => {
          console.log("escape")
          if (event.key === "Escape" && isFullScreen) {
            if (!warningShown) {
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent exiting full screen on first Escape
              alert("Press Escape again to end the test.");
              setWarningShown(true);
            } else {
              exitFullScreen();
            }
          }
        };
    
        // Setup and cleanup of the event listeners for the Escape key
        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleEsc);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEsc);
        };
      }, [warningShown, isFullScreen]); // Depend on warningShown and isFullScreen
    
      // Handle changes in the full-screen status
      useEffect(() => {
        const handleFullscreenChange = () => {
          const isCurrentlyFullScreen = document.fullscreenElement != null;
          setIsFullScreen(isCurrentlyFullScreen);
          if (!isCurrentlyFullScreen) {
            setWarningShown(false); // Reset warning when leaving full screen
          }
        };
    
        document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);
        document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);
        document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);
        document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", handleFullscreenChange);
    
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener("fullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);
          document.removeEventListener(
            "webkitfullscreenchange",
            handleFullscreenChange
          );
          document.removeEventListener(
            "mozfullscreenchange",
            handleFullscreenChange
          );
          document.removeEventListener(
            "MSFullscreenChange",
            handleFullscreenChange
          );
        };
      }, []);
    
      const handleStart = () => {
        console.log("handleStart");
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          {!isFullScreen ? (
            <button onClick={goFullScreen}>Start Test</button>
          ) : (
            <>
              <h1>Test is running...</h1>
              <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }


Do you get any errors in your console

You can use the fullscreenchange event to detect when the fullscreen mode changes, such as when the "Esc" button is pressed. By handling this event, you can prompt the user with a confirmation dialog and, if the user decides to stay in fullscreen mode, re-enter fullscreen.

The Escape key handling for exiting full screen is handled by your browser and does not trigger the keydown event. By design, websites are not able to prevent a user for exiting full screen. This would cause a pretty major security issue where websites are able to lock users into their sites and prevent them from leaving, so browsers do not allow it.
TL;DR: this is not possible.
